# Кто рендерит HTML для SPA

Tags: php, rest, spa

Есть сайт, сделанный по SPA архитектуре. Он работает с PHP движком через REST API.

Находил такие примеры:

- ->Сайт посылает запрос движку
- ->движок собирает данные
- ->подставляет данные в шаблон
- ->и из всего этого рендерит html страницу
- ->отправляет ее клиенту

Но так же прочитал, что SPA сам рендерит для себя страницы, а движок лишь отправляет ему данные, и эти данные SPA уже сам подставляет в шаблоны. То есть движок ничего не знает о том как выглядят страницы, он только отправляет данные, например в json.

Так кто же все таки рендерит страницы? Клиент или движок?
Или оба этих способа рабочие?

Comment: Как сделаете, так и будет :) ВКонтакте, например, активно использует оба способа

Comment: Но вообще «мейнстримный» SPA это обычно javascript-муть на каких-нибудь Angular/React/Vue. Упоминая SPA, чаще всего подразумевают рендеринг на клиенте и какой-нибудь REST API с JSON, хотя это не является единственным способом создания SPA

Comment: Спасибо всем, разобрался